# Debugging/inspecting values inside a function

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, ghci

Consider the following contrived example :

```
module Main where
myadd3 first second third = 
  let result1 = first               -- line 3
      result2 = second              -- line 4
      result3 = third               -- line 5
  in result1 + result2 + result3    -- line 6
```

I would like to inspect the values of `result1`, `result2`, and `result3` by the time I reach line 6. However when I step through the code, at no point do any of these "computations" appear to be available for inspection :

```
*Main> :break 3
Breakpoint 0 activated at Main4.hs:3:17-21
*Main> :break 4
Breakpoint 1 activated at Main4.hs:4:17-22
*Main> :break 5
Breakpoint 2 activated at Main4.hs:5:17-21
*Main> :break 6
Breakpoint 3 activated at Main4.hs:6:6-32
*Main> myadd3 2 3 4
Stopped at Main4.hs:6:6-32
_result :: a = _
result1 :: a = _
result2 :: a = _
result3 :: a = _
[Main4.hs:6:6-32] *Main> :step
Stopped at Main4.hs:6:6-22
_result :: a = _
result1 :: a = _
result2 :: a = _
[Main4.hs:6:6-22] *Main> :step
Stopped at Main4.hs:3:17-21
_result :: Integer = _
first :: Integer = 2
[Main4.hs:3:17-21] *Main> :step
Stopped at Main4.hs:4:17-22
_result :: Integer = _
second :: Integer = 3
[Main4.hs:4:17-22] *Main> :step
Stopped at Main4.hs:5:17-21
_result :: Integer = _
third :: Integer = 4
[Main4.hs:5:17-21] *Main> :step
9
```

That is we have lines like `result1 :: a = _` but not something like `result1 :: a = 2`. Is this because of the lazy nature of haskell?, and if so is there a way to inspect `result1`, `result2`, and `result3` at the moment values are bound to them? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct that the behavior is due to laziness. To force evaluation you can do:

```
[debug.hs:6:6-32] *Main> :print result1
result1 = (_t1::a)
[debug.hs:6:6-32] *Main> :force result1
*** Ignoring breakpoint
result1 = 2
[debug.hs:6:6-32] *Main> :step
Stopped at debug.hs:6:6-22
_result :: Integer = _
result1 :: Integer = 2
result2 :: Integer = _
```